# Value detected of type null when passing data via routes in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, routes

[image: The error message]

> This error just been a while before the data passed successfully from loading screen.

The loading screen that passing data :

> if i print the instance on here, the error is not appeared

```
void setupWorldTime() async {
    WorldTime instance = WorldTime(location: 'Jawa Timur', flag: 'jakarta.png', url: 'Asia/Jakarta');
    await instance.getTime();
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home', arguments: {
      'location': instance.location,
      'flag': instance.flag,
      'time': instance.time,
    });
  }
```

The home screen which is receiving data :

```
Map data = {};
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    data = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map;
    print(data['location']);

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextButton.icon(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/location');
                },
                icon: const Icon(Icons.edit_location),
                label: const Text('Edit Location'),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
                Text(
                  data['time'],
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 30,
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

print(data['location']); printing the data perfectly, but before it the error above showing instantly, is that mean the print method expected the value of data is null before it is receive the value? how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `setupWorldTime` is an async function and will not call the `Navigator.pushReplacementNamed` bit until `instance.getTime()` has returned. Because your home screen starts without its arguments set, `data = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map` will set data to null, leading to your error. Only once `instance.getTime()` has returned will `build()` be called again, this time with `data != null` and your message disappears.

To fix this, in your `build` function you should test for `data == null` and show something else (like a loading indicator) if data is indeed still null, or use a `FutureBuilder` (preferred).

Comment: thanks, you save my day!